# JAX-WS generating WSDL cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, classnotfoundexception, wsgen

I'm stuck on this and I don't see why.
I have a java class with annotation to make it into a webservice. I Had the plan to generate the proper WSDL with wsgen so that the other module of the project can use it to generate their client classes.
But everytime I try to generate the wsdl i'm stuck with the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` And I don't know :

1. Is it normal for `wsgen` to look for this class ?
2. What can I do to provide it to `wsgen` given it should have it.

Additionnal informations :

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

$ wsgen -version
wsgen version "2.2.9"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the spring-web jar. Pls include this & try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```